# Ck Editor initialize issue in angular while page initializing second time after saving

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Iam using the CK Editor in my angular project, it is getting loaded properly for the first page initialized. For the second time control is not getting rendered properly also am getting the error message. Thanks in advance.

I have tried to re-initialized for the second time, but that is not working or I have missed any code.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined

Comment: Have you searched the error message already in case someone else has had this issue? Do you have a minimal sample of code that can reproduce the issue so someone here can help?

Comment: You have missed to add your code into question